# Recover Clipboard Screenshot on Win 10

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, clipboard

I took a screenshot with printscreen, pasted it to mspaint, and didn't have chance to save it, since my computer crashed.

Is there any way to either recover that image from mspaint, or recoved the screenshot from clipboard somehow, with Win 10?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to recover the screenshot.

Next time, press <kbd>[image: newwinlogo] Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> to save the screenshot in the Screenshots folder automatically (for Win 8, 8.1, 10).

Comment: Did not know this existed... wow!